# merge several columnts with NAs into one

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several columns with **non-overlapping** data in it:

```
a <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(NA, 20))
b <- c(rep(NA, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(NA, 10))
c <- c(rep(NA, 20), rep(3, 10))
data <- cbind(a, b, c)
```

an output:

```
       a  b  c
 [1,]  1 NA NA
 [2,]  1 NA NA
 [3,]  1 NA NA
 [4,]  1 NA NA
 [5,]  1 NA NA
 [6,]  1 NA NA
 [7,]  1 NA NA
 [8,]  1 NA NA
 [9,]  1 NA NA
[10,]  1 NA NA
[11,] NA  2 NA
[12,] NA  2 NA
[13,] NA  2 NA
[14,] NA  2 NA
[15,] NA  2 NA
[16,] NA  2 NA
[17,] NA  2 NA
[18,] NA  2 NA
[19,] NA  2 NA
[20,] NA  2 NA
[21,] NA NA  3
[22,] NA NA  3
[23,] NA NA  3
[24,] NA NA  3
[25,] NA NA  3
[26,] NA NA  3
[27,] NA NA  3
[28,] NA NA  3
[29,] NA NA  3
[30,] NA NA  3
```

What is the way to collapse these N columns (there are much more than 3) into one using `dplyr`, so

```
result <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 10))
```

Of course in the real data instead of `(1, 2, 3)` the actual data is something completely different and its only common property is that it is not `NA`.

Comment: `dplyr::coalesce` maybe?

Answer (score 3):

In base R,

1. For numeric, you could use `rowSums`

```
    rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE)
```

2. For non-numeric, `max.col` can be used to identify the columns with non `NA` values

```
   data[cbind(1:NROW(data), max.col(!is.na(data)))]
```

Comment: it seems that `data %>%   transmute(newcol = coalesce(a, b, c))` does the trick